# How to get return value of Rf_lang1(SEXP) from a pointer to the SEXP?

Tags: c, r

Inside C, I have a SEXP x and a pointer to it: double
*ptr_=REAL(x). For convenience, I pass ptr to other C functions
to work with x. One of these other C functions has a bug, but I
figured out that if I pass x directly to it and work with
Rf_lang1(x), the function works as expected. My question now is:
How can I work with ptr instead of x directly (to avoid having to pass x)?
I tried things like Rf_lang1(ptr) or Rf_lang1(*ptr) but they don't work.

A minimal working example is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271543/how-to-call-rs-order-function-from-within-c-via-r-ordervector) and a previous version of the problem is described [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-convert-a-C-vector-to-an-SEXP-for-using-it-in-R-orderVector-td4704043.html) (no answers).

Comment: You'd avoid all these troubles by using Rcpp.  And you could still program "C-style" if you wanted to...

Comment: Hi Dirk, I know, I know... but this related to something we might need for base R and thus I would like to figure out how it works in 'plain C'. At this point, I am also just interested to see where my thinking is wrong, so my goal is to fix this the 'old-fashioned way' :-)